# How to make A2DP and HSP work simultaneously

Tags: audio, bluetooth, communication, headset, a2dp

I have a bluetooth headset. When connecting it to Windows 10, it installs two profiles in Playback devices list:

1. Hands-Free. (HSP profile)
2. Stereo. (A2DP profile)

The Second one (Stereo) is set to be the "Default Device" and the "Default Communication Device" on the system.

When I start any program that uses the mic (recorder, chat, VoIP Calls, gaming, etc.) The sound suddenly stops working And I can only use the mic until I stop the recorder or the call.

To enable the sound again I need to make the Hands-Free (HSP) profile handle both input and output (sound and mic). Unfortunately, HSP gives really poor sound quality.

I want to know If there is a way, using code,  I can change Bluetooth behavior so the two profiles work simultaneously. One handles the sound and one handles the mic so I can have high quality sound and use the mic at the same time.

Comment: Usually not. Only one sound device can be in use and one has the nice stereo sound, another has mic.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably never find a solution. I had the same problem (I was trying to create a walkie talkie with 2 headsets connected to the same smartphone).
On Windows (but also on Android) you can't access directly to a BT-microphone or BT-speaker because it is automatically detected as BT headset and the OS take the control of the device.
Your app can then access the OS-device and not directly the hardware device. The only OS able to do that was Symbian I think which had the most BT-protocols. On Windows you will probably never be able to do that and on Android you have to write your own A2DP-protocol if you want to access the device directly without OS interference.

So sad...

Comment: So, is this still impossible 3 years later?

Comment: I never tried it again. But with all the problems we have with bt and android 10, I think it is even more difficult now.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, under windows you can define different devices for communications and sound.
So, you have two choices:

- Choosing Hands-free for both mic/speaker only for communication (which will switch back to A2DP after the call/teams).
- Choosing another mic for communication which allow you to still use the speaker profile even in communication.

That is a bluetooth restriction : A2DP (high quality audio) cannot be use simultaneously with HFP (hands-free profile)